# Solution of Non linear coupled ode with finite boundary conditions

Tags: code-request

i want to solve these two non linear ode. can any one help me.
any vale for `c1, c2, c3,m, pr` and `Re` can be taken

```
DSolve[{(1 + c1) f''''[x] - c2 g''[x] - 
    Re [f'[x] f''[x] - f[x] f'''[x]] + M*f''[x] == 0, 
  c3 g''[x] + c1 Subscript c2 (f''[x] - 2 g[x]) - f[x]' g[x] + 
    g[x]' f[x] == 0, θ'' + Pr*Re*f*θ' == 0, 
  f[1] == f[-1] == 0, f'[1] == f[-1] == 1, 
  g[1] == g[-1] == 0, θ[-1] == θ}, {f, g}, x]
```

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site) and [Hints and help on using the site efficiently](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/hints-and-help-on-using-the-site-efficiently) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and read the [FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: `Re` is a built in function, not a variable, you can't take the derivative of `f` with respect to `g` or vice versa.

Comment: Problems I see are 1. `c1 Subscript c2` using subscripts as variable names can wreak havoc. 2. `f[x]' g[x] + g[x]' f[x]`. Maybe you meant for example `f'[x]g[x] + g'[x]f[x]`. 3.` \[Theta]` should be a function of `x` and included in the list of outputs. 4. `Pr*Re*f*\[Theta]'` You need to place the arguments of `Re` in brackets. 5. `\[Theta][-1] == \[Theta]`, again arguments. Good luck!

Comment: You seem to using `Re` both as a parameter and a function. You can't do that.